# Как вывести случайные символы по их коду в Unicode

Tags: java, случайные-числа, unicode

Пытаюсь вывести символы Unicode в диапазоне 9398, 10178.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Unicode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand_char = new Random();
        int number = 10178;
        int unicode = rand_char.nextInt(number) + 9398;
        char smile = (char)('\u' + r.nextInt(unicode));
        System.out.println(smile);

    }
}
```

Возникают проблемы с '\u' в создании переменной.Как можно решить это, чтобы в программе могли выводиться рандомные символы в диапазоне?

Comment: https://javatutorialhq.com/java/lang/character-class-tutorial/tochars-codepoint-method-example/

Comment: \uXXXX то только для литералов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно `\u` - просто приводите числовой код символа к `char`:

```
Random rand_char = new Random();
int number = 10178;
int unicode = rand_char.nextInt(number) + 9398;
char smile = (char)(unicode);
System.out.println(unicode);
System.out.println(smile);
```

[Пример вывода](https://ideone.com/5jLhgK):

```
12564
ㄔ
```

Проверяем: https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=12564

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]